# Struggling with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a simple google spreadsheet link.

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/kdfaghlkdghidubtinvieorn/edit#gid=12345`

I have following **regextract** which extracts the ID of the link:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"(?:/d/)(.*)(?:\/edit)")`

It seems to have the desired effect.

I am trying to recreate this in google scripts but I'm not getting the same answer.

```
function regex() {
    var link = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/kdfaghlkdghidubtinvieorn/edit#gid=12345";
    var regExp = new RegExp("(?:\/d\/)(.*)(?:\/edit)", "gi")
    var id = regExp.exec(link)[1];
    Logger.log(id)
}
```

Comment: What answer do you get, then?

Comment: @NikxDa I get the following:
`/docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/kdfaghlkdghidubtinvieorn`

Answer (score 1):

Try `(?:\gid=.*)`

So you'll get the id as **gid=12345**

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to match those letters after the /d/ just fine. 
Maybe you get better results if you're looking for wordcharacters between slashes,  instead of that greedy `.*` ?

```
\/d\/(\w+)\/
```

example snippet:

```js
function getIdFromLink(link){
  let regExp = /\/d\/(\w+)\//;
  return regExp.exec(link)[1];
}

var link  =  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/kdfaghlkdghidubtinvieorn/edit#gid=12345";

var id = getIdFromLink(link);

//Logger.log(id)
console.log("id: "+ id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the syntax I don't know why but wrapping another bracket around seems to resolve the issue:

```
(?:(\/d\/))(.*)(?:\/edit)
```